# Integration between Jenkins and JIRA Cloud

Tags: java, jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-rest-api

I'd like to add a new comment to the JIRA Cloud after one of my job is finished. I've tried jira-plugin, jira-ext and many more, but with no sufficient effect.
jira-ext plugin works in someway, but not at all. I cannot set it as a post build action (only build step). It's the reason why i do not have access to the variables like $STATUS, $BUILD_NUMBER.
I know that I can use somekind of REST notification and send a message directly by http protocol, but i'd like to use existed plugin.

Which plugin do you use to integrate Jenkins with JIRA Cloud? 
Could anyone describe step by step how can we set it properly for JIRA Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate what exactly your want to do?

In fact your have to set integration between Jira and Jenkins from Jira side.
First of all we need to know what exactly we want to see at jira. At my infrastructure i want to now what developer do by jira issue so we use smart commits to bitbucket and gihub and Jira automatically link commit and issue.
[Here some small manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/integrating-with-development-tools-802592222.html) Also if you wish something else you can use [this jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) it can prepare release notices update issues do something else this plugin use rest and works with cloud and standalone instances of Jira